# Use multiple variables in single string interpolation kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

[image]

##### How should can I use multiple var in single ${}

```
fun main() {
    var a = 5
    var b = 20

    if (b % a == 0 && b > a++)
        print("statement 1st - ${a--, --b}")

    if (a % 5 == 0 || a >= b++)
        print("statement 2nd - ${a--, --b}")
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't really possible, also, how the compiler could know what do you want to display? eg.: 25? 2,5? 2.5? 2 5 ?

Comment: Any reason you want them to specifically be inside a single interpolation block? Something like `print("statement 1st - ${a--}, ${--b}")` should technically work.